# configuring esbuild with react (replacing create-react-app)

Tags: reactjs, esbuild

I have a bunch of files with the extension `js` instead of `jsx`. (This is a react project).

I setup my package.json for build with such script:

`"build": "esbuild src/App.js  --bundle --minify --sourcemap --outfile=public/bundle.js",`

Upon running it, I have tons of errors all complaining about `js` syntax such as:

```
const App = () => {
 return (
  <>
   // some code
  </>
 )
}
```

where:

```
> src/App.js:16:2: error: Unexpected "<"
    16 │     <>
       ╵     ^
```

This is a similar error for many files that have basic div's as return: `<div> // content </div>` stating that the `<` in the begging of the `div` is unexpected. I assume this is because it's not viewing these files as `jsx`. Is there some sort of flags I can set that will solve this? Changing every single file to a `jsx` is going to be a mission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like there is a statement in the `esbuild` [docs](https://esbuild.github.io/content-types/#jsx): (bottom of the linked block)

`esbuild app.js --bundle --loader:.js=jsx`

the `--loader:.js=jsx` statement will use the `jsx` loader on `js` files

So your script may look something like:

```
"build": "esbuild src/App.js --bundle --minify --sourcemap --outfile=public/bundle.js --loader:.js=jsx",
```

The docs state you can also do this within a config script and not the CLI:

```
require('esbuild').buildSync({
  entryPoints: ['app.js'],
  bundle: true,
  loader: { '.js': 'jsx' },
  outfile: 'out.js',
})
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm migrating a create-react-app full system to Vite. And had this problem, i cannot just rename the extension of hundreds of files at once.

On Vite 4. It's possible to override some eslint rules. You can see the full discussion and solutions evolution on github. https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/3448

The solution i'm using is just reconfigure the `vite.config.js` file.
The solution is setting to optimize all files equally without differentiate plain js from jsx.
The best solution will be on the future rename all files to correct extensions, this way the optimizer generate the best results.

The clean file with  the workaround solution:

```js
import { defineConfig, transformWithEsbuild } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),

    // Workaround
    {
      name: 'load+transform-js-files-as-jsx',
      async transform(code, id) {
        if (!id.match(/src\/.*\.js$/)) {
          return null;
        }

        // Use the exposed transform from vite, instead of directly
        // transforming with esbuild
        return transformWithEsbuild(code, id, {
          loader: 'jsx',
          jsx: 'automatic', //  this is important
        });
      },
    },
    // End workaround

  ],

  // Workaround before renaming .js to .jsx
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      loader: {
        '.js': 'jsx',
      },
    },
  },
  // End workaround



})
```

PS: If you are adding the code to your existing vite.config. There is an extra import from vite for the workaround.

Answer (score 2):

This can also happen when you forget to add the import directive [for the React library] to your component files.

For example, let's say you have a React app with the following structure:

```
.
+-- index.html
+-- index.js
+-| src
    +-- app.js
    +-| components
        +-- my-component.js
+-| dist
    +-- bundle.js
```

And the following file contents:

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
// index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './src/app';

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App/>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

```
// ./src/app.js

import Banner from './components/my-component';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
      </header>
      <main>
        <Banner/>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
// .src/components/my-component.js

function MyBanner(){
  return (
    <h3>My Banner!</h3>
  );
}

export default MyBanner;
```

To bundle your React app with ESBuild, you may be running something like this:

```
npx esbuild index.js --bundle --loader:.js=jsx --out-file=./dist/bundle.js
```

> **Note**: You can use `npx esbuild` instead of `./node_modules/.bin/esbuild` if your npm version is 5.2.0 or higher.

After the build is complete, and you open `index.html` [in the browser], you should get an error saying `React is not defined`.

The reason for this is that in `./src/app.js` and `./src/components/my-component.js`, there is no import directive for React. So when the JSX is converted to `React.createElement` during the build process, there is no declared and accessible reference to React when your bundle executes in the browser; hence the error.

To fix this, add the import directive at the top of both files.

```
import React from 'react';
```

> **Note**: It might be useful to run your build with and without the import directive to see how the code changes with each build.